# Replacing single digit numbers with double in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input field where u enter in numbers. I want it so that if the user enter in a single-digit number, it adds a 0 in front of it (so 7 will be 07). For some reason, my code is not working.

Javascript:

```
    function formatNum(ele) {
      console.log($("#" + ele.this).val() < 10);
      if ($("#" + ele.this).val() < 10) {
          console.log("CLICKED2!")
          $("#" + ele.this).val("0" + $("#" + ele.this).val());
      }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<input class="time-input" onkeypress="validate(event)" onBlur="formatNum(this)" type="text" id="focus-input-secs" value="00" maxlength="2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `not` calling the right `element` in your function. `this` return the HTML. We need to `$(this)` so that `.val()` can be used on the element.

You can do this `two` ways either using simple `if/else` or use `ternary operator` to be more `simplified` one line code.

**Using `if` / `else`**

```js
function formatNum(ele) {
  if ($(ele).val() < 10) {
    $(ele).val(0 + $(ele).val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="time-input" onBlur="formatNum(this)" type="text" id="focus-input-secs" value="00" maxlength="2">
```

**Using [ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**

```js
function formatNum(_this) {
  //Ternary Operator
  let output = $(_this).val() < 10 ? 0 + $(_this).val() : $(_this).val()
  //Add value
  $($(_this).val(output))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="time-input" onBlur="formatNum(this)" type="text" id="focus-input-secs" value="00" maxlength="2">
```